# Remove key sensitive

Tags: java

I have a Map with the username as a key and the User object.

The problem is that I have a username key called `John` and `username = "john"` so it doesn't get the user.

How do I remove key sensentive key from the Map?

```
List<User> usersList = User.getUsers();
Map<String,User> users = usersList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(User::getUsername, Function.identity()));

//check the online users
for(String username : activeUsers.getUsers()) {
    User user = users.get(username);
}
```

Comment: Change both to all-uppercase (or lowercase) for the purpose of comparison

Comment: how?????????????

Comment: No. Inside `activeUsers.getUsers()` is `john` and the `users` Map has `John`

Comment: The map shouldn't know case-related issues.

Comment: Then make the key as `getUserName().toLowercase()` as @FedericoklezCulloca says. Or use a case-insensitive map. Or fix `activeUsers` to contain the proper value (this is probably the root of the issue and should be investigated as it may cause similar problems all over your application).

Comment: yes, and Frederico has provided you with a workaround. or, you could re-write your code to use an equalsIgnoreCase

Comment: Are you suppose to only find one `John` in the map ? Can you have `John`, `john`, `JOHN`, `JoHn`, ... ? Username are case sensitive so this can be interesting to know.

Comment: @AxelH "Username are case sensitive" in almost every system I've ever used, no they're not.

Comment: You want an example of case sensitive usernames @Michael, a small system called UNIX. This is possible so this need to be confirm by OP. He is the one that can tell if this need to be or not. Unless you know his project.

Comment: @AxelH Regardless of the bad design decisions of a 50 year old system, the fact that he's asking for a case-insensitive lookup **necessarily implies** that the username is case insensitive. Suppose there are two users: 'John' and 'JOHN'. The active username is 'john'. Which user should I get in this case?

Comment: Or implies that this was not expected @Michael. Incomplete analyze is not uncommon. (This is my last comment about that, you seems to camp on your position so this isn't necessary to chat in the comment section).

Answer (score 0):

Simply convert everything to the same case:

```
List<User> usersList = User.getUsers();
Map<String,User> users = usersList.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        user -> user.getUsername().toUppercase(), // uppercase everything in the map
        Function.identity()
    )
);

//check the online users
for(String username : activeUsers.getUsers()) {
    User user = users.get(username.toUppercase()); //uppercase the username in the comparison
}
```

It does kind of beg the question as to how (and why) two "identical" usernames are existing in your system in different cases. **That** should probably be the problem you should address, else you'll wind up with this uppercase conversion littered all over your codebase.

---

See also [`org.apache.commons.collections4.map.CaseInsensitiveMap`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-collections/apidocs/org/apache/commons/collections4/map/CaseInsensitiveMap.html) which does exactly the same thing for you:

> Before keys are added to the map or compared to other existing keys,
>   they are converted to all lowercase

Comment: The thing is that this **could** require a `MultiMap` to work the same way. You will not be able to put `John` and `JOHN` in the same map. What the original solution **could** do.

Comment: @AxelH We do not need to support that case. He never said the map contained mix-case keys. To quote his comment: "No. Inside `activeUsers.getUsers()` is `john` and the users Map has `John`"

Comment: "It does kind of beg the question as to how (and why) two "identical" usernames are existing in your system" - I'd guess it's from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50153056/simple-but-big-security-risk-on-my-website

Comment: To be fair, he never said it would not contained mix-case keys either... so we can both be right. (Waiting for the answer). PS, check SO about usernames distinction. Of course, the usage of the map is not the best idea in that context.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate the `EntrySet` and remove based on a condition using [`Collection.removeIf`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-)

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("Foo", "0");
map.put("Bar", "1");
map.put("foo", "2");

map.entrySet().removeIf(e -> e.getKey().equalsIgnoreCase("foo"));

System.out.println(map);
```

> {Bar=1}

This will not require to update each key for other purposes.

Comment: Usually the whole point of using map is for fast lookup, else you could just use a `List<Pair<K, V>>`

Comment: Usually I use `ID` key in a `map` and not names that can have different cases @Michael ;) but sometimes bad practice for us to use bad solution. I agree this is "better"  to uppercase everything but this mean you lose the original case of the ID, which **can** be a problem. This is why I provide the alternative.